# What causes primordial gravitational wave in the early universe?

Tags: gravitational-waves, polarization

Is it collision between primordial black holes or perhaps big bang itself, I read that if we can observe very first polarized light e.g. CMBR etc then inflation theory is proven. So my question is what's polarizing those very first light and how was it possible? Actually I'm more interested could gravitational wave polarize light? If so how?

P.s. kindly use equation sparingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the present cosmological model, the [Big Bang model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang):

[image]

In the very beginning before the particles in the standard model with the charges and other quantum numbers appear , before 10^-32 seconds from the origin, quantum gravity is supposed to reign supreme, with a  quantum mechanical particle/field called [inflaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation_(cosmology)) which homogenizes everything to an accuracy of 10^-5 ( taken from the homogeneous to that accuracy [cosmic microwave background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background) radiation).

At the time of 10^-32 seconds the [standard model particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) start appearing , whith charges etc, and the photon there. All particles interact gravitationally , by construction of the theory. The gravitational waves generated during the inflation period from the inflaton field will also, within the standard theory, be interacting with the existing soup of primordial particles .

The space polarization of photons will be different if they come from an interaction with a gravitational wave, than with quarks or electrons , and this can be modeled and checked, whether it exists  in the radiation patterns  of the CMB. This is the objective of the [BICEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BICEP_and_Keck_Array) experiments.

If seen it will be a confirmation of the existence of gravitational waves, which in the present model will be coming from the inflation period, as black holes neutron stars and their mergings come much later in the timeline of the Big Bang, after the formation of neutral hydrogen which leads to stars etc.